# ElasticSearch high-availability setup

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, failover

I'd like some insight on ElasticSearch nodes for trying to set up a proper high-availability setting:

(disclaimer: I'm fairly new to ES, so if there's some misconception on my concepts, I'd deeply appreciate if you can highlight it)

Current setup is a cluster with three nodes, which automatically delegate master node responsiblity between themselves, and all three are data nodes. The client application (.NET) is hardcoded to direct requests to one specific node, so when that node is down the whole cluster is unreachable from the client application.

Mostly from what I can grasp from the [the ES site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html), I can set data-less nodes as dedicated managing nodes, to avoid that process overhead on the data loads. I can also set client nodes that handle the searching and merging overhead, and keep data nodes data-dedicated.

For high-availability, it seems like the preferred option is to use a connection pool on the client side containing all the nodes from the cluster, so it'd direct requests to other nodes if the first option is unreachable.

From all of this, I was considering setting the cluster with TWO no-data, no-http nodes to work as managing nodes, and let them failover each other. Also, set up TWO no-data, no-master nodes to work as "entry nodes", while leaving the current 3 nodes as no-master, no-html, and leave them dedicated to data handling only. Then, I'll just pool the two entry nodes on the client application.

So final setup will be 2 master nodes, 2 entry nodes, 3 data loads.

Does that sound reasonable ?

Thanks a lot for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about the required performance shape of your app, it's hard to say more than your proposed architecture passes the basic smell test.  You'd want to spec out more regarding shard replication, expected write vs. read activity ratios and similar to give more specific feedback.

However... there is no reason whatsoever you should have to hard-wire your client to a specific ES node, or to do anything with a request other than sending it to a master.  Sending a request anywhere other than a master is a Bad Idea and sort of pointless anyway: every request ultimately routes to a master which: a) directs a set of workers (sometimes dual data/workers, sometimes just data) to query shards and then b) passes results back to the master, which then assembles them and returns the overall response payload to your client.

Pool your two/however many masters under a load balancer and configure your client to direct activity to the load balancer.  Much cleaner and probably better performing, to say nothing of much more easily scalable.

Comment: If I set N-master nodes & M-data nodes (with node.master: false), and set a number of "client nodes" (with node.master: false & node.data: false, having http.enabled: true while the rest of the cluster has http.enabled: false), if I direct requests to these "client nodes", will they still redirect requests to the master for handling the data gather & processing?

From what I could read, it seems like these client nodes will do that work without relying on the master nodes. I was planning on setting a connection pool and seed it with those client nodes.

Comment: Yes this will work as you intend.   The client nodes will handle query scatter/ response gather without involving the master nodes.   I misread your load balancer intentions to mean you'd allow request processing on the data nodes as well, which you would not want.  LB in front of the client nodes accomplishes exactly what you are looking for.  Good luck with your new cluster.